# How can I change the source data range selected within a Pivot Table for use in a Pivot Chart

Tags: excel, pivot-table, vba

Currently I have my pivot table which looks like this

[image: Pivot Table which is used]

At the moment, one of the graphs which I create adds a series to a xlPie chart however It is selecting the data in `Range("C6:C12")` where I would prefer it selects the Second last column, `Range("F6":"F12")` as we are wanting the total values, not just the values for one month.

This is the pie chart currently created for reference:

[image: Pie Chart which I generate]

To create this chart, I use the following code within the sheet this chart resides:

```
Dim shpPie As Shape
Set shpPie = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart(xlPie)

shpPie.Chart.SetSourceData Source:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Pivot Table").PivotTables(1).TableRange1, _
                      PlotBy:=xlColumns
With Range("A1:F32")
    shpPie.Left = .Left
    shpPie.Top = .Top
    shpPie.Width = .Width
    shpPie.Height = .Height
End With
With shpPie.Chart.PivotLayout.PivotTable
    .PivotFields("Marketspace").Orientation = xlRowField 'Row Field is the Axis Fields
    .PivotFields("Page Name").Orientation = xlRowField
    .PivotFields("Year").Orientation = xlColumnField
    .PivotFields("Month").Orientation = xlColumnField 'Column Field is the Legend Fields
End With
```

I assumed that the issue is with this line here:

```
 shpPie.Chart.SetSourceData Source:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Pivot Table").PivotTables(1).TableRange1, _
                          PlotBy:=xlColumns
```

In excel, that line gives me a source data selection of:

```
=SERIES('Pivot Table'!$C$3:$C$5,'Pivot Table'!$A$6:$B$14,'Pivot Table'!$C$6:$C$14,1)
```

Does anyone know if there is anything I can do to make it select the 2nd last column, or another technique to do this? I would like it to select the 2015 total's not the January data.

I have tried changing the source line generated from:

```
=SERIES('Pivot Table'!$C$3:$C$5,'Pivot Table'!$A$6:$B$14,'Pivot Table'!$C$6:$C$14,1)
```

to:

```
=SERIES('Pivot Table'!$C$3:$C$5,'Pivot Table'!$A$6:$B$14,'Pivot Table'!$F$6:$F$14,1)
```

just to see what happens but it will not allow me to apply that change.

I'm new to VB so I may be misunderstanding how these pivot tables/charts work

Comment: You can't change what data a pivot chart uses. You would have to create a regular chart, or use a copy of your pivot table that only shows the 2015 total data.

Comment: Aaah ok, In that case, I'll extract this data for a new chart to be created :)  Thank you for the reply, @Rory

Answer (score 0):

no need to extract the data to create new chart, just copy the worksheet containing the pivottable (as suggested by Rory), exclude the field "Month" from the Values in the copied pivottable.

Exclude the following line from your code

```
.PivotFields("Month").Orientation = xlColumnField 'Column Field is the Legend Fields
```

Then run you procedure for the copied worksheet